# Github REST API - How to edit a blob for a specific branch

Tags: python, rest, github, python-requests, github-api

I have the following python code (included everything for completeness):

```
import base64
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import os

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github+json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {os.environ.get("GITHUB_BEARER_TOKEN")}'
}

def get_file_info(org, repo, branch, file_path):
    url = f'https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repo}/contents/{file_path}?ref={branch}'
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    if not res.ok:
        print(res)
        return None
    
    return res.json()

def write_file(org, repo, branch, file_path, file_content, blob_sha=None, commit_msg=''):
    url = f'https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repo}/contents/{file_path}?ref={branch}'
    data = {
        'message': commit_msg,
        'committer': {'name': 'name', 'email': 'email@gmail.com'},
        'content': base64.b64encode(bytes(file_content, 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    }
    if blob_sha:
        data.update({'sha': blob_sha})

    res = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=data, verify=False)
    if not res.ok:
        print(res.status_code)
        print(res.text)
        return None
    
    return res.json()


file_info = get_file_info('user', 'repo', 'main', 'Pipfile')
pprint(write_file('user', 'repo', 'main', 'Pipfile', 'new_content', file_info.get('sha'), 'test commit'))
```

This is resulting in the following message from the github api though:

```
409
{"message":"Pipfile does not match 123","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/repos/contents#create-or-update-file-contents"}
```

I've found the cause of the error, just not sure how to get around it. This seems to occur when a file has the same blob sha across branches, as is the case when you cut a new branch and don't make any changes to a file. I guess github only recognizes the original branch as the owner of that blob sha, or something like that, haven't been able to find any documentation on it. So, when I try invoking my `write_file` function, passing in the original upstream branch as the ref, it is able to successfully write, but I am interested in editing the file in the downstream branch... any ideas?